# Catch-All global exception handler in App Engine for Python

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, catch-all

Is it possible to create a catch-all global exception handler in Google App Engine using Python?

Basically, I want to catch all un-caught exceptions and gracefully handle it, while sending an email with the traceback to me.

Currently, for all uncaught errors, the users see a stacktrace with a snippet of code in it. This is undesirable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You can do it using the [ereporter](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter.html) package that allows to receive exception reports from your application by email.

Ereporter will report two kind of exceptions:

- exceptions logged with `logging.exception('Your handled exception')`
- any uncaught exceptions

To catch all the exceptions, I would create a custom BaseHandler class overriding the [handle_exception()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html) method; all your request handlers should inherit from this Base class.
Have a look to [Custom Error Responses](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Custom_Error_Responses) too.

Here is a simple example of BaseHandler class:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
        if debug_mode:
            webapp.RequestHandler.handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode)
        else:
            logging.exception(exception)
            self.error(500)
            self.response.out.write(template.render('templdir/error.html', {}))
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems to solve half my problem, but when this is enabled what will the user see when an un-caught exception occurs? Is there someway to redirect the user to a default error page for all unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Thanks! I am not that great at python, could you please include a code snippet on how to do this for the webapp.RequestHandler class? Would really appreciate.

Comment: Awesome! So now when I will create a new class to handle lets say the "/" url, I will have to use class MainPage(BaseHandler) instead of the usual class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler) ... am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call the original handle_exception by calling the following in your BaseHandler:

```
webapp.RequestHandler.handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode)
```

Here it is in context.

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import sys
import traceback

class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
        from main import emaildevs
        emaildevs('An error occurred on example.com', ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
        webapp.RequestHandler.handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode)
```

Answer (score -4):

try:
  call
except:
  sendemail

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I am aware how to catch errors. My question is how can I catch errors globally in my application running in GAE