# when to use try/except blocks in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

I've recently started developing my first web app with GAE and Python, and it is a lot of fun.

One problem I've been having is exceptions being raised when I don't expect them (since I'm new to web apps).  I want to:

1. Prevent users from ever seeing exceptions
2. Properly handle exceptions so they don't break my app

Should I put a try/except block around every call to put and get?
What other operations could fail that I should wrap with try/except?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch-All global exception handler in App Engine for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296504/catch-all-global-exception-handler-in-app-engine-for-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a method called `handle_exception` on your request handlers to deal with un-expected situations.

The webapp framework will call this automatically when it hits an issue

```
class YourHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def handle_exception(self, exception, mode):
        # run the default exception handling
        webapp.RequestHandler.handle_exception(self,exception, mode)
        # note the error in the log
        logging.error("Something bad happend: %s" % str(exception))
        # tell your users a friendly message
        self.response.out.write("Sorry lovely users, something went wrong")
```

Comment: That's a great solution for (1).  For (2), I guess I need to make sure that any failures will not put my app in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Yes, this is your "last resort" catch. If you are making lots of datastore writes and there are situations that might leave inconsistant data, use [transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html). But try to keep transactions to a minium in appengine, as they can cause problems if you don't fully understand the datastore.

Comment: Good answer, though the implementation you show for `handle_exception` is extremely similar to the default one. Instead, you can override `self.error()` to output helpful error pages; `handle_exception` calls `self.error(500)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your views in a method that will catch all exceptions, log them and return a handsome 500 error page.

```
def prevent_error_display(fn):
    """Returns either the original request or 500 error page"""
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            # ... log ...
            self.response.set_status(500)
            self.response.out.write('Something bad happened back here!')
    wrap.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return wrap


# A sample request handler
class PageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
    @prevent_error_display
    def get(self):
        # process your page request
```

Comment: If you set the response status to 500 then the task will be retried again and again. So, if there is something wrong with your code, then you will be depleting your quota.