# Python GAE: How to return JSON-formated response even when an error occurs?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, error-handling

In my GAE application, I have several request handlers that return JSON-formated response. When one of these is called, if an error occurs (exception, or programming error), the output is not JSON: it is the stack trace.

What I need is:

```
Output without error:
{
    "foo" : 1
    "bar" : 2
    "status" : "OK"
}

Output when an error occurs:
{
    "status" : "ERR"
    "errorMessage" : "An error occurred!"
}
```

**My question is**: What is the best practice to make sure that, in any case, the output will be a JSON-formated response? Of course, a common solution for every request handlers would be great.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - use the ereporter class (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296664/336505), but create a custom BaseHandler that formats your uncaught exceptions as JSON output:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      self.response.out.write(etc, etc) # format the exception
```

Comment: This solution seems to match my needs! I'm quite a newbie in Python and I read that multiple inheritance is possible. So would you recommend to make my existing `A` class to derive from both `BaseHandler` and `RequestHandler` ? Or make `BaseHandler` derive from `RequestHandler`, and then make my existing `A` class derive from `BaseHandler` ?

Comment: Hi Morgan - I would suggest trying to do the latter: "make BaseHandler derive from RequestHandler, and then make my existing A class derive from BaseHandler"

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs, to avoid getting a stack trace or other ugly output, you will need to employ a try ... except: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

e.g.

```
try:
    # ... your code ...
except TypeError as e:
    # ... do something with this error type
except:
    # ... generic exception catchall
    # output that JSON response
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, I already tried a try/except statement. But I need a more general solution to apply to **every** request handlers.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `try... except...` is the only way of catching errors in Python. You have to have it in there. To apply it to everything you just need to put it at a higher level in your code and then in your `except` statement work out which request handler you're using and tune the output accordingly.

Comment: @GTF It's not the only way... check the other answer.. The question is for Google App Engine :)