# How to automatically get email alerts on errors in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, error-handling

I maintain a lot of Google App Engine apps and it is very difficult to constantly keep a track of all my servers if they are running smoothly.

It is very embarrassing to wake up only after user complains about a system crash.

Is it possible to constantly get updated about my server health?

Can i get a mail or something in case their is a error on my google app engine application?

Can't wait for Google to take up this requirement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can schedule a cron job which can do this for you

First create a entry in *cron.yaml*

```
- description: Houston we have a problem Finder
  url: /errorfinder/
  schedule: every 3 hours
  timezone: Asia/Kolkata
```

Then create an entry in *app.yaml*

```
handlers:
- url: /errorfinder/
  script: errorfinder.app
  secure: always
```

Now keep *errorfinder.py* with the following content

```py
import base64
import datetime
import logging
import time
import urllib
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api.logservice import logservice
from google.appengine.api import mail

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):    
      # Set up end time for our query.
      end_time = time.time()
      start_time = end_time  - 10800 # 3 hours before now . same as cronjob interval
      html = ''
      report_needed = False
      # Iterate through all the RequestLog objects, displaying some fields and
      # iterate through all AppLogs beloging to each RequestLog count times
      for req_log in logservice.fetch(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, minimum_log_level=logservice.LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, include_app_logs=True):
            report_needed = True
            html = html + '<br /> REQUEST LOG <br />'
            html = html + 'IP: %s <br /> Method: %s <br /> Resource: %s <br />' % (req_log.ip, req_log.method, req_log.resource)
            html = html + 'Date: %s<br />' % datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(req_log.end_time).strftime('%D %T UTC')

            for app_log in req_log.app_logs:
                html = html + '<br />&emsp; APP LOG<br />'
                html = html + '&emsp; Date: %s<br />' % datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(app_log.time).strftime('%D %T UTC')
                html = html + '&emsp; Message: <b>%s</b><br />' % app_log.message
                html = html + '<br /><br /><br /><br />'
      if(report_needed):
           mail.send_mail(sender="Beagle Bot <bot@urdomain.com>",
                to='lazyadmins@urdomain.com',
                subject='Houston we have a problem ..',
                body=html,
                html=html,
                reply_to='support@urdomain.com')
      self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/errorfinder/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

You can make the error search close to real time by reducing the cron job interval

Answer (score 17):

Now it is possible with `Stackdriver` (acquired by Google and integrated with Google Cloud Platform/App Engine).

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/errors.
2. Click `Turn on notifications`

[image]

Comment: @HimalayanCoder This should be marked the best answer now.

Comment: It's under Monitoring, and it's offered with a free trial. You must create a Stackdriver account, and can select the free basic tier at the end of 30 days. Just activated mine. Found this thread looking for e-mail notificaiton of GAE logging errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic way to send alarm mails in case of errors.

You will need to make your own solution: create a [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) that [parses logs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/) and [sends email](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail) about errors. Possibly aggregate similar errors together. Instead of emails you might consider automatically creating an error report in your issue tracking system.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this link did the trick:
https://console.cloud.google.com/user-preferences/communication?project=voilanorbert-1272&utm_source=cloud-notification&utm_medium=email&utm_content=unsubscribe-new-error

[image]

To access it, click on the three dot near your avatar on the top right, and select "Preferences".

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your app to send you an email when exceptions are raised.  See here for more details: [Catch-All global exception handler in App Engine for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296504/catch-all-global-exception-handler-in-app-engine-for-python)