# Can AppEngine automatically send me an email when I log an error in the app?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, notifications

I have a python app in the GAE Standard Environment and I log errors using the builtin python logging api:

```
logging.error('some error')
```

This error then appears in StackDriver Logging correctly as an error log item.

Is there a setting somewhere which I could set so I get an email notification when a new error log item is added to StackDriver Logging?

Note that I don't mean the StackDriver Error Reporting page. That is something else, the above error  does not appear there, because for StackDriver Error Reporting items AFAIK I need to use some specific API call.

I mean the StackDriver Logging viewer where standard python logs appear. Can I set a notification there, so I get an email when StackDriver Logging receives an error log item from my python app?

Comment: FWIW, I was pleasantly surprised to get email notifications from Google about new errors encountered in my apps (that have been running for a while). I don't recall doing anything specific for that.

Comment: Are these errors logged by you in the app? Do these errors also show up in StackDriver Error Reporting? (https://console.cloud.google.com/errors)   Because if so then you probably do something else than builtin python logging.

Comment: Ah, I missed that point. No, these were unintended tracebacks causing server-side 500 errors. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, `logging.error` does not appear in StackDriver Error Reporting, but `logging.exception` does.

So the solution is raising an exception in your code and then catching it and using `logging.exception`. In this case the error goes to StackDriver Error Reporting  and you get a notification (because the log item has a stack trace, so it knows it's an error).

Alternatively, you don't have to catch your own exception,you can let it fly, you get a notification in that case also, but then the server returns 500, so by catching it you can exit more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Error Reporting Subscribing to notifications](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#subscribing_to_notifications) from google cloud console

or

Using [AppEngine LogService][2], you can fetch all error logs from appengine/stackdriver, and you need to set cron job to fetch error logs and send email with that errors.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655135/8055450